# SSD Drive failed after a while

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

My SSD will be gone ( not detectable ) after a while.

It's installed "Windows 10 Family Edition" and patched to the latest.

It was pretty OK before windows patch ( the patch before 1803), I think it's 16xx something. That moment is the first time this happened. Which caused me to re-install the OS into the HDD because SSD drive just gone missing.

After using HDD for a while, the SSD appeared again itself as a secondary hard drive. For speed reason, I still want to use it. So I reinstalled the OS on SSD. But after like 1 day or 2, the SSD will be gone missing again.

I have to fall back to "other O.S" ( the one on the HDD) and keep using the PC and wait for the SSD to appear back again.

Is it the SSD having problem? How can I check this?

Here is a SSD healthy checking tool ( CrystalDiskInfo) report.

[image]

Comment: Your SSD has a problem. If still under warranty, ask for replacement.